# AngularDart Filter call method throws error when 'items' is null

Tags: dart, angular-dart

When I load a component using 'filter', the 'call' method is being run before the 'items' parameter is being set.  So I am getting repeating errors from line 200.  Eventually, 'items' is sent and the 'call' method runs without error.

```
The null object does not have a method 'where'.

NoSuchMethodError: method not found: 'where'
Receiver: null
Arguments: [Closure: (dynamic) => dynamic]

STACKTRACE:
#0      Object._noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:42)
#1      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:45)
#2      Filter.call (package:angular/formatter/filter.dart:200:26)
```

This is the first time I have implemented filter using AngularDart, and this is happening in both components I've tried.  There's nothing special in my template:

```
<tr ng-repeat="appSession in appSessions | orderBy: orderByList | filter: filterObject">
```

The appSessions list is either set by an attribute or if not provided, in attach method.  In this case, it is being set by the attribute.

```
@NgOneWay("app-sessions") List<AppSessionModel> appSessions;
@NgOneWay("mobile-user-id") int mobileUserID;

void attach() {

    if (appSessions == null) {
        if (mobileUserID != null) {
            appSessionManager.getForUser(mobileUserID).then((sessions) {
                appSessions = sessions;
            });
        } else if (!fromUserTable) {
            appSessionManager.getOpen().then((sessions) {
                appSessions = sessions;
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Has anyone else experienced this?  Is there a timing bug here?

Thanks,
Sam

Comment: Can you please add a bit more code? How is the value set?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I added the code that is setting 'appSessions'.  Nothing unusual as far as I can tell.  I have another component where the list contains maps, not objects, and I still get this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After more debugging, I confirmed that my list was never null in the 'attach' method, and I confirmed that Filter.call was running after the 'attach' method.  It turns out that the problem related to the 'orderBy' in the template.

I had this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="appSession in appSessions | orderBy: orderByList | filter: filterObject">
```

If I switch 'orderBy' and 'filter', then no more Filter.call error:

```
<tr ng-repeat="appSession in appSessions | filter: filterObject | orderBy: orderByList">
```

I debugged OrderBy.call, but it is not returning 'items' as null, so the problem seems to be somewhere between OrderBy and Filter, but I don't know enough about AngularDart to know what that might be.

Answer (score 0):

You could just initialize the field with an empty list

```
List<AppSessionModel> appSessions = [];
```

Comment: That didn't work.  The error seems to be thrown before the attribute is mapped, but I haven't debugged to that level of detail.

Comment: Ensure that `appSessions` isn't set to `null` in `attach()`